# notepad++ Remove text between, if does not contain specific element

Tags: notepad++

Does anybody know how i can remove all text parts which contain specific element by using notepad++. Here is original text example:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT

SUMMARY: [V: 1/3]

END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT

SUMMARY: [V: 2/3]

END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT

SUMMARY: [V: 3/3]

END:VEVENT
```

And in the end there should be removed all text except those which have: [V: 3/3] element between: BEGIN:VEVENT and END:VEVENT. Here is how it should look like in the end:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT

SUMMARY: [V: 3/3]

END:VEVENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

**Edit:**
Let's do it using brute force:

Find what: `\RBEGIN:VEVENT\RUID:.*\RLAST.*\RDTS.*\RDTS.*\RDTE.*\RSUMMARY:.+\[V: [^3]/3\]\RDESC.*\RLOCA.*\REND:VEVENT`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

Make sure you've checked `Regular Expression` **but not** `dot matches newline`, then click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have just tried it. It replaces all content which begin from BEGIN:VEVENT and end to END:VEVENT with NOTHING. Can you check if there is some mistake.

Comment: @user1566903: Sorry I haven't fully tested. Now I should work.

Comment: Yes it works, but is there a way to check only for [V: 3/3].  Without checking for "SUMMARY:" because in some lines i have some text which is other than SUMMARY

Comment: Thanks it works great. But how i can make that it replaces content even if there is any data between BEGIN:VEVENT and END:VEVENT. Because now it only works when there is empty lines between them. Here is example: BEGIN:VEVENT Any content can be here SUMMARY: [V: 1/3] Any content can be here END:VEVENT

Comment: When i add some text between BEGIN:VEVENT and SUMMARY: [V: 1/3] it works, but if text is between SUMMARY: [V: 1/3] and END:VEVENT it is not working.

Comment: @user1566903: I've done a typo, it's a dot `.` not a semicolon `;` at the end.

Comment: Now i really do not know what is the problem. I am attaching you file which i am working with: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B96q-C7gfh9aTWNvWkppeG56MUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @user1566903: It should work now, tested on your sample file.